# Fundamental query regarding MDM

Tags: ios, token, mdm

I'm a newbie to MDM and am still trying to figure out how all the pieces fit together. Have a query I hope the Gurus can help answer.

Is the following correct? From the moment it registers itself with Apple, each device maintains a persistent connection with the APNS service via the "apsd" deamon. This connection serves as the underlying "pipe" that helps the apsd deamon, on its part, offer the publish-subscribe service that helps client apps (aka the subscribes) receive "messages" from the publisher (aka APNS in this case). If this is true then

My query concerns how a device gets its unique token from APNS. Per my understanding, an application needs to register itself with APNS for it to be able to receive notifications...and as a part of this registration process, the APNS service returns a unique App Specific "token" to the app...how does this pan out in the MDM context...what's this app? Who decides the topic to use? The reason for me to ask this is because the MDM Check-In protocol requires the device to send the "Topic" and "Token" during the final TokenUpdate step. Without an app, where does the "Topic" and "Token" come from?

Any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regds

Answer (score 0):

The `Topic` comes from the MDM profile.
The Token is generated by `mdmd` on the device itself.